Engine management light flashing at around 80 on a 2012 corsa d petrol 1.2
my corsa d 2012 plate had had the engine management ligjt flash for the 2nd time in a few weeks when going above 70 in 5th gear. When I slow it stops it's a 1.2l with 106,000 miles on it.
Recently had rac out to fix a plug which I know need a new one but his temporary fix is fine. Also trying to get a relay to fix a problem with inside blower, lights, cigarette light etc. Is it possible that these are tied to my issue. Just in case I'm able to kill 2 birds with 1 stone.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the engine management light is flashing, there may be a code associated with it. If you plug in an OBDII reader, you might be able to see something in the background. From your description, I don't think there'd be an association between the engine management light and the temporary fix you talk about (if I understand what you're saying correctly).
